# An open-source note-taking app that facilitates drawing/handwriting?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, note-taking, ocr

I don't know [what kind of hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17858/a-pad-for-note-taking-primarily) my device will be yet, but I imagine that it'll be a detachable 2-in-1 that runs Linux. As stated in that link, I plan to get help to add some function(s) into the app, so I assume it's open source and allows "modding". The software must:

- Support writing with a pen/stylus
- Possess OCR tech that can translate an image to text (and can be turned on or off).
- Can be further programmed to add more features/modules.

Some desired features:

- Easy to organize.
- Be free, or at least has a free version for education.
- Can flip a file horizontally, like in a mirror, without having to open a separate image editor, do it manually, and import the compatible output back to this app.
- Allows customizable templates that can be modified on the fly. For example, I may want to format the file with dimensions of an A4 paper, with pre-drawn lines that divide it into areas for the Cornell system. If during a lecture, I run out of space to write but doesn't want to switch to a new page, I can toggle the "format paper" mode on, and expand the width/height in 5 seconds.

If the software is not designed for the assumption of a laptop machine and Linux OS, kindly remark it in your answer. Also, please advise me whether any of the desired features are unavailable atm, and thus need to be programmed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like [Nebo](https://www.nebo.app/). It is not for Linux, and not open source, but there is a Windows version available. Maybe that one runs under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), haven't tried, bceause I use the paid iOS App/Version, occasionally.

Nebo have just expanded their free plan, perhaps due to competitive pressure. So the "gratis" tier is quite generous.

Which Stylus device do you intend to use under Linux, and which distribution?

Comment: Hey thanks! I haven't received any answer in the hardware question linked in the OP, so idk. But if it's Linux, then I think Mint. The 5-page free plan of Nebo seems a bit limiting. But my biggest concern is that it isn't open source... I want the app to have the feature of spaced repetition reminder, which I guess few, if any, have. So it must be open source in order to be expanded with some new modules.